# Would I be able to restrict Pricebook visibility?

Tags: security

Would i be able to Restrict visibility into pricebooks?

I would only want certain people to select a pricebook. Currently I am granting access using hierarchies.

Would it be possible to restrict it via profiles or roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can share pricebook using roles groups (not profiles) -

To view and manage sharing details, click Sharing on the price book detail page. The Sharing Detail page lists the users, groups, roles, and territories that have sharing access to the price book.

here is the link to SFDC doc - https://cs17.salesforce.com/help/doc/user_ed.jsp?loc=help&target=products_sharing.htm&section=Products
[image]

Comment: I am not able to see Territory sharing option in Pricebook. Any reason ?